# My sql query not returns null value rows with not in condition

Tags: sql-server

My query is:

```
SELECT (SUM(credit)-SUM(debit)) AS balance
FROM member_transaction
WHERE member_id=" + mId + " AND reference_id NOT IN (
    SELECT user_reference_id FROM r_request WHERE status=7)
```

But it's not returning rows which has `NULL` in `reference_id` column.
Is there anything wrong in my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to this

```
SELECT (SUM(credit) - SUM(debit)) AS balance
FROM member_transaction
WHERE member_id = " + mId + "
    AND isnull(reference_id, 0) NOT IN (
        SELECT user_reference_id
        FROM r_request
        WHERE STATUS = 7
        )
```

Comment: Assuming 0 is not a legal id in that other query.

Comment: You may want to fix syntax.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to include the null rows, it's best to be explicit:

```
SELECT (SUM(credit)-SUM(debit))AS balance
FROM member_transaction
WHERE member_id=" + mId + " AND
      (
         reference_id NOT IN(
            SELECT user_reference_id FROM r_request WHERE status=7)
         OR reference_id IS NULL
      )
```

SQL uses a [three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) where comparisons with `NULL` generally produce the third logic value, `UNKNOWN`, rather than `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Also return referece_id null rows

```
SELECT (SUM(credit)-SUM(debit))AS balance FROM member_transaction 
WHERE 
    member_id=" + mId + " 
    AND ( (referece_id is null) or 
          (reference_id NOT IN
              (SELECT user_reference_id FROM r_request WHERE status=7))
```

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` values are automatically eliminated from main query **if sub-query returns some result**. However if sub-query does not have a record to return, then only `NULL` values will be returned.

So you can use

```
SELECT (SUM(credit)-SUM(debit))AS balance 
FROM member_transaction 
WHERE member_id=" + mId + " 
AND (reference_id NOT IN
(SELECT user_reference_id FROM r_request WHERE status=7) OR reference_id  IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually yes, you are not considering `NULL`s in column `reference_id`. In order to consider `NULL`s you should explicitly define an `OR` condition.

Make the following query. It will be `sargable` and will use potential indexes on column `reference_id`:

```
"SELECT (SUM(credit)-SUM(debit)) AS balance
 FROM member_transaction
 WHERE member_id=" + mId + " AND (reference_id IS NULL OR reference_id NOT IN (
    SELECT user_reference_id FROM r_request WHERE status=7))"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the usage of an left join instead of an not in, as it could be quite slow on a huge r_request table.

```
SELECT (SUM(credit) - SUM(debit)) AS balance
    FROM member_transaction mt
    LEFT JOIN r_request r
            ON mt_dat.reference_id = r.user_reference_id
    WHERE member_id = " + mId + "
        AND r.user_reference_id is null
```

This should exactly do what you want.

Best regards,
Ionic